# Understanding logistic growth

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The population growth can be modelled by the function ${dP\over dt}=rP(1-{P\over k})$ and $P$ will go from $P_0$ (the initial value) to $k$.

But, I am trying to understand the behaviour of the term $f(P)=P(1-{P\over k})$. So, I solved the ODE equation ( ${dP\over dt}$) over time (using Matlab ode 45) and stored the value of $P$ at each time point. Then using these $P$ values I plotted $P(1-{P\over k})$. This is the code and the result of $f(P)$ in log scale.

```
p=1000;
time=100;
[t,y]=ode45(@(t,y)LogisticEq(t,y),0:time,p);

k=10^5;
figure
plot(t/24,y(:,1).*(1-(y(:,1)/k)))

function s= LogisticEq(~,y)

r1=0.5;
k=10^5;
s=zeros(1,1);

s(1)=r1*y(1)*(1-(y(1)/k));

end
```

[image]

In here, it can be seen that $f(P)$ is negative for some values. Is it possible for $f(P)$ to be negative? $f(P)=0$ for $P=0$ and $P=k$ and as the maximum value of $P$ is $k$, why does $f(P)$ become negative?

What does it mean for $f(P)$ to be negative?Does it mean that over time the population decreases?

Is there a condition that can be posed to have only positive values for $f(P)$?

Comment: I can't see any negative values. The lowest term of your y-axis is $10^{-1} >0$ and x-axis starts from $0$. In order, thought, for someone to properly understand the problem, I think you should give a rigorous explanation of every variable/function and their given domains-restrictions.

Comment: @Rebellos The "blank" spaces in the plot correspond to negative values of $f(P)$, since what's being plotted is $\log f(P)$.

Comment: @rafa11111 The function seems rather continuous so it doesn't make much sense what's happening if we can't see domains and restrictions and not properly understand what each thing is.

Comment: @Rebellos I agree that the question is far from being clear. I just wanted to point out that the graph has logarithmic $y$ axis.

Comment: As t is indepent of the right hand side, P is a linear function.

Comment: The function is $$P(t)=\frac{k\, P_0\,e^{rt} } {k+(e^{rt}-1)P_0 }$$

Comment: @rafa11111 I know the solution of $P(t)$. What I want to know is for each $P(t)$ as $t$ varies what happens in the ODE, specifically for the term $f(P)$. What does it mean for $f(P)$ to be negative and how can it be negative

Comment: @rafa11111 I guess my question is related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236959/logistic-growth-and-curve for the case where the solutions move to minus infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $f(P)$ given by
$$
f(P)=P\left(1-\frac{P}{k}\right)
$$
we have $f(P)<0$ if $P<0$ (which is not reasonable) or if $P>k$. It means that the system cannot support a population larger than $k$; in other words, $k$ is "so-called carrying capacity (i.e., the maximum sustainable population)" (according to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html)). If we are searching for a steady state solution we must set $dP/dt=0$. Therefore, we have $P=0$ or $P=k$, which means that, if the population is zero or if the population achieved the 'carrying capacity', the population won't change anymore.

Since $P=k$ is a *fixed point* of the system, we can also see the behavior of $P$ when it's close to $k$. If $P=k+\Delta P$, we have
$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = r f(k+\Delta P) = r \left( (k+\Delta P) \left( 1 - \frac{k+\Delta P}{k} \right) \right) = -r \left( \Delta P + \frac{\Delta P^2}{k}\right) \approx -r\Delta P,
$$
where I dropped out $\Delta P^2$ because I assumed $\Delta P$ very small. If $P$ is close to $k$, but a bit larger, we have $P=k+\Delta P$ with positive $\Delta P$. Since close to $P=k$ we have $dP/dt \propto -\Delta P$, $P$ *decreases* until reaching $P=k$. On the other hand, if $P$ is slightly smaller than $k$, $P$ will *increase* until reaching $P=k$. However, since the 'velocity' with which $P$ changes is proportional to the distance to $k$ (remember that $dP/dt \propto \Delta P$) $P$ never actually reaches $k$, but tends asymptotically to it. You can use 
$$
\frac{dP}{dt} \approx r(k-P)
$$
to show that $P \to k+C \exp (-rt)$ as $P\to k$.

Of course, all of this is useless, since we know the analytical solution for $P$, which is
$$
P(t) = k P(0) \frac{\exp(rt)}{k+P(0)(\exp(rt)-1)},
$$
as Claude Leibovici stated in the comments. I only did all this asymptotic stuff to show, without resorting to plottings, that $f(P)$ can be negative, but *cannot change its sign*. We saw that $f(P)$ can only change its sign if $P$ 'cross' the line $P=k$ (or $P=0$, which is out of question). However, we also saw that $P$ always approaches $P=k$ asymptotically. Therefore, $f(P)$ cannot change its sign.

I tried to replicate your results, without success. I can't tell exactly is wrong with your code, but I'm not sure if you should specify the time array that way; when I used MATLAB I usually specified only the initial and final time (like `timespan = [t0 tend]`) and left to the integrator to choose the inner points.